# How can I avoid duplicates when generating a random list of pairs of numbers?

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have the following code to set 10 random values to true in a boolean[][]:

```
    bommaker = new boolean[10][10];
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    for (int i=0; i<=9; i++) {          

        a = randomizer.nextInt(9);
        b = randomizer.nextInt(9);
        bommaker[a][b] = true; 
    }
```

However, with this code, it is possible to have the same value generated, and therefore have less then 10 values set to random. I need to build in a checker, if the value isn't already taken. And if it is already taken, then it needs to redo the randomizing. But I have no idea how to do that. Can someone help me?

Comment: Keep track of the previously-used indices, like in a `Set` where each member is a tuple, although there are other options.

Answer (score 6):

simplest solution, not the best:

```
for (int i=0; i<=9; i++) {          
    do {
        a = randomizer.nextInt(10);
        b = randomizer.nextInt(10);
    } while (bommaker[a][b]);

    bommaker[a][b] = true; 
}
```

Comment: I would edit this slightly by changing it to: while (bommaker[a][b]);    Because you only want to set the bomb only if it isn't there already. But other than that, good answer.

Comment: And why wouldn't this be the best? :) I was thinking about keeping a `HashSet` of used indices, but I much prefer your approach!

Comment: @tzaman because this approach may end up calling `nextInt()` more times than you need, you could use a Knuth shuffle to avoid the inner while loop.

Comment: @sverre - good point. Not particularly worrisome in this case, though, until the "fill factor" approaches the size of the array.

Answer (score 4):

You're problem is similar to drawing cards at random from a deck if I'm not mistaken...

But first... The following:

```
randomizer.nextInt(9)
```

will not do what you want because it shall return an integer between [0..8] included (instead of [0..9]).

Here's Jeff's take on the subject of shuffling:

http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/12/shuffling.html

To pick *x* spot at random, you could shuffle your 100 spot and keep the first 10 spots.

Now of course seen that you'll have only 10% of all the spots taken, simply retrying if a spot is already taken is going to work too in reasonable time.

But if you were to pick, say, 50 spots out of 100, then shuffling a list from [0..99] and keeping the 50 first value would be best.

For example here's how you could code it in Java (now if speed is an issue you'd use an array of primitives and a shuffle on the primitives array):

```
    List<Integer> l = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        l.add(i);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(l);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[l.get(i)/10][l.get(i)%10] = true;
    }
```